# How do i automatically upload my code on Github repository

Tags: github

I am setting up my Github repository and i created my Gitpage. I m working on a project and i want my code to get directly  commit on my git account. How to do it?

I tried to clone my git on command prompt but its not working

Comment: Please don't add incomplete questions. They don't actually provide any information to the user, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you earn enough reputation, you will gain privileges to upvote answers you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See Why is voting important.

Comment: Please provide the command you are having trouble with at least, and let us know if the repository already exists on Github or not. Without this information, this question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

> `git clone` is primarily used to point to an existing repo and make a
>   clone or copy of that repo at in a new directory, at another location.

If you have created your repo on GitHub, you should be able to use the following command to create a new directory on your computer

**Clone with HTTPS:** *Use Git or checkout with SVN using the web URL.*

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repository.git
```

Comment: I'd like to add a cheat sheet that helped me greatly when I first started using Git as my main method of source control: https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/files/git_cheat_sheet.pdf. This includes several basic commands for day to day operations.